# Cantor set has dimension zero

Tags: metric-spaces, cantor-set

Define 'zero-dimensional' as follows: for every pair of closed disjoint sets $A,B$ in a metric space $X$ there exist disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $A \subseteq U$, $B \subseteq V$ and $X = U \cup V$.

What is a direct way to prove that the Cantor set $C$ (defined by removing open middle thirds from $[0,1]$ or by considering numbers with only $0$s and $2$s in the ternary expansion) with the Euclidean metric satisfies this property? I struggle to come up with anything as I find it difficult to work with $C$ and its open/closed sets.

Comment: Did you try using the fact that a subset is closed in the subspace topology iff it is the intersection of a closed set of the larger space with the subspace? Moreover I think you can reduce to the case that the closed sets are given by intervals intersected with the Cantor set...

Comment: @PrudiiArca I am aware of the former but not really sure how it helps; the latter I don't really see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SKETCH: Perhaps the easiest approach is to prove that your definition of *zero-dimensional* is equivalent to the usual one for a compact Hausdorff space $X$: $X$ is zero-dimensional if it has a base of clopen sets.<sup>1</sup> Both directions are fairly easy to prove. Then show that $C$ has a base of clopen sets by showing that its complement is dense in $\Bbb R$ and considering open intervals whose endpoints are in the complement.

<sup>1</sup> Your definition implies the clopen base definition in any $T_1$ space. If $U$ is an open nbhd of $x$, $\{x\}$ and $X\setminus U$ are disjoint closed sets, so there is a clopen set $V$ such that $x\in G\subseteq U$. The clopen base definition implies yours if $X$ is also compact. If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint closed sets, for each $x\in A$ let $U_x$ be a clopen nbhd of $x$ disjoint from $B$. By compactness there is a finite $F\subseteq A$ such that $A\subseteq\{U_x:x\in F\}$, and $\bigcup_{x\in F}U_x$ is then a clopen nbhd of $A$ disjoint from $B$.

The two properties really are distinct in general. A space with yours is usually said to be *strongly zero-dimensional*, though I’ve also seen such spaces called *ultranormal*.

Comment: I can see how that shows that $C$ has a clopen base. However, I wouldn't know how to construct the desired $U$ and $V$ given that such a base exists or vice versa.

Comment: @MMFTSBU: The direction that you need right now is from clopen base to $U$ and $V$. Here you can take advantage of the fact that $C$ is compact. For each $x\in A$ let $U_x$ be a clopen nbhd of $x$ disjoint from $B$. $\{U_x:x\in A\}$ is an open cover of the compact set $A$, so it has a finite subset that covers $A$. Can you finish it to get $U$?

Comment: Ah, yes I was just about to edit my comment to say that I managed to prove that direction using compactness: taking $U$ to be the union of the sets in the finite subcover, which is still clopen, so that $V = C\setminus U$ is again (cl)open and covers $B$ while being disjoint from $U$ by definition. So does this work only after assuming something more, like compactness here?

Comment: @MMFTSBU: I’d have to think about it to be sure, but I believe so, yes. The other direction, though, needs nothing more than $T_1$. If you have the separation property, let $x\in X$, and let $U$ be an open nbhd of $x$. Then $\{x\}$ and $X\setminus U$ are disjoint closed sets, so there is a clopen $V$ such that $x\in V\subseteq U$.

Comment: @MMFTSBU: Yes, you definitely do need extra: the clopen separation version is actually what is often called strong zero-dimensionality or, sometimes, ultranormality.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I've been told that the rationals (and irrationals) should also satisfy the stronger definition; would I need a completely different argument to prove those?

Comment: @MMFTSBU: You’re welcome! Yes, zero-dimensionality implies strong zero-dimensionality for Lindelöf spaces and hence for separable metric spaces. Get a countable cover $\{G_k:k\in\Bbb N\}$ by clopen sets, each of which meets at most one of $A$ and $B$. For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $U_n=G_n\setminus\bigcup_{k<n}G_k$ to get a cover by pairwise disjoint clopen sets, each of which meets at most one of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113049/discussion-between-mmftsbu-and-brian-m-scott).